# What is the value of X?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

`24    6   63`

`132   4   14`

`23    x   17`

The answer is either : 21, 14, 3 or 2

Comment: Where does this puzzle come from?

Comment: You went here too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2943755/what-is-the-value-of-x-21-14-3-or-2

Comment: Is this a coincidence: https://www.facebook.com/rgnblk/posts/24-6-63-132-4-14-23-17parantez-i%C3%A7indeki-say%C4%B1larla-sat%C4%B1rdaki-say%C4%B1lar-bulunmu%C5%9F-i%C5%9Fe/1060879777289989/

Comment: I will reiterate what I said already on math.se.  There is not enough information to uniquely determine an answer.  Here are two different rules you could follow and still get an answer from your answer key.  Given a row `x   y   z`, take the leading digit from `x` and multiply this by the one's digit of `z` to make `y`.  You have `2*3 = 6`, you have `1*4=4` and so you have `2*7=14` and so with this you have 14 as the answer.

Comment: An equally valid answer: given a row `x   y   z`, compare `x` and `z`.  Whichever is bigger, add all digits except the one's digit together and use this to make `y`.  `63` is bigger than `24` so the middle of the first row is `6`.  Meanwhile `132` is bigger than `14` so `1+3=4` is the middle of that row.  The last row then would be `23   2   17` since `23` is bigger than `17`, so you have $2$ as the answer.  Both examples are totally contrived and there is nothing suggesting which answer is the "better" answer.  Similarly contrived examples exist with the other answerkey choices as answers.

Comment: I am totaly convinced that the answer is 14 although 2 is logical too, which I've found earlier. Anyway, thank you very much for your time, effort, understanding. You've been very helpful.

Comment: "*I am totally convinced that the answer is 14*"  How are you totally convinced?  You shouldn't be.

Comment: I have another question like that, and it can be solved by using this rule. Also, the answer is correct, so yes I am convinced. But in general you can never be sure of anything, I agree with that one.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It's in my sister's book.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> **14.**
> RULE: divide the 'x' value by the ten's digit of the first number, and concatenate the quotient to the right of the first digit of the 'x' number.

Comment: If I understand the 'rule' properly, should the second line not be 132 4 44 instead of 132 4 14?

Comment: Yeah you seem to be correct, but I got my answer anyway.